# running for loop until arbitrary index (python 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, indexing

So I have these strings that I split by spaces (' ') and I just rolled them into a single list I called 'keyLabelRun'
so it looks like this:

keyLabelRun[0-12]:

```
0 OS=Dengue
1 virus
2 3
3 PE=4
4 SV=1
5 Split=0
6
7 OS=Bacillus
8 subtilis
9 XF-1
10 GN=opuBA
11 PE=4
12 SV=1
```

I only want the elements that include and are after "OS=", anything else, whether it be "SV=" or "PE=" etc. I want to skip over those elements until I get to the next "OS="

The number of elements to the next "OS=" is arbitrary so that's where I'm having the problem.

This is what I'm currently trying:

```
OSarr = []
for i in range(len(keyLabelrun)):
    if keyLabelrun[i].count('OS='):
        OSarr.append(keyLabelrun[i])
        if keyLabelrun[i+1].count('=') != 1: 
            continue
```

But the elements where "OS=" is not included is what is tripping me up I think.

Also at the end I'm going to join them all back together in their own elements but I feel like I will be able to handle that after this.

In my attempt, I am trying to append all elements I'm looking for in order to an new list 'OSarr'

If anyone can lend a hand, it would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

These list of strings came from a dataset that is a text file in the form:

```
>tr|W0FSK4|W0FSK4_9FLAV Genome polyprotein (Fragment) OS=Dengue virus 3 PE=4 SV=1 Split=0 
MNNQRKKTGKPSINMLKRVRNRVSTGSQLAKRFSKGLLNGQGPMKLVMAFIAFLRFLAIPPTAGVLARWGTFKKSGAIKVLKGFKKEISNMLSIINKRKKTSLCLMMILPAALAFHLTSRDGEPRMIVGKNERGKSLLFKTASGINMCTLIAMDLGEMCDDTVTYKCPHITEVEPEDIDCWCNLTSTWVTYGTCNQAGEHRRDKRSVALAPHVGMGLDTRTQTWMSAEGAWRQVEKVETWALRHPGFTILALFLAHYIGTSLTQKVVIFILLMLVTPSMTMRCVGVGNRDFVEGLSGATWVDVVLEHGGCVTTMAKNKPTLDIELQKTEATQLATLRKLCIEGKITNITTDSRCPTQGEATLPEEQDQNYVCKHTYVDRGWGNGCGLFGKGSLVTCAKFQCLEPIEGKVVQYENLKYTVIITVHTGDQHQVGNETQGVTAEITPQASTTEAILPEYGTLGLECSPRTGLDFNEMILLTMKNKAWMVHRQWFFDLPLPWTSGATTETPTWNRKELLVTFKNAHAKKQEVVVLGSQEGAMHTALTGATEIQNSGGTSIFAGHLKCRLKMDKLELKGMSYAMCTNTFVLKKEVSETQHGTILIKVEYKGEDVPCKIPFSTEDGQGKAHNGRLITANPVVTKKEEPVNIEAEPPFGESNIVIGIGDNALKINWYKKGSSIGKMFEATARGARRMAILGDTAWDFGSVGGVLNSLGKMVHQIFGSAYTALFSGVSWVMKIGIGVLLTWIGLNSKNTSMSFSCIAIGIITLYLGAVVQADMGCVINWKGKELKCGSGIFVTNEVHTWTEQYKFQADSPKRLATAIAGAWENGVCGIRSTTRMENLLWKQIANELNYILWENNIKLTVVVGDIIGVLEQGKRTLTPQPMELKYSWKTWGKAKIVTAETQNSSFIIDGPNTPECPSVSRAWNVWEVEDYGFGVFTTNIWLKLREVYTQLCDHRLMSAAVKDERAVHADMGYWIESQKNGSWKLEKASLIEVKTCTWPKSHTLWSNGVLESDMIIPKSLAGPISQHNHRPGYHTQTAGPWHLGKLELDFNYCEGTTVVITENCGTRGPSLRTTTVSGKLIHEWCCRSCTLPPLRYMGEDGCWYGMEIRPISEKEENMVKSLVSAGSGKVDNFTMGVLCLAILFEEVMRGKFGKKHMIAGVFFTFVLLLSGQITWRDMAHTLIMIGSNASDRMGMGVTYLALIATFKIQPFLALGFFLRKLTSRENLLLGVGLAMATTLQLPEDIEQMANGIALGLMALKLITQFETYQLWTALISLTCSNTIFTLTVAWRTATLILAGVSLLPVCQSSSMRKTDWLPMAVAAMGVPPLPLFIFGLKDTLKRRSWPLNEGVMAVGLVSILASSLLRNDVPMAGPLVAGGLLIACYVITGTSADLTVEKAADITWEEEAEQTGVSHNLMITVDDDGTMRIKDDETENILTVLLKTALLIVSGIFPYSIPATLLVWHTWQKQTQRSGVLWDVPSPPETQKAELEEGVYRIKQQGIFGKTQVGVGVQKEGVFHTMWHVTRGAVLTYNGKRLEPNWASVKKDLISYGGGWRLSAQWQKGEEVQVIAVEPGKNPKNFQTMPGTFQTTTGEIGAIALDFKPGTSGSPIINREGKVVGLYGNGVVTKNGGYVSGIAQTNAEPDGPTPELEEEMFKKRNLTIMDLHPGSGKTRKYLPAIVREAIKRRLRTLILAPTRVVAAEMEEALKGLPIRYQTTATKSEHTGREIVDLMCHATFTMRLLSPVRVPNYNLIIMDEAHFTDPASIAARGYISTRVGMGEAAAIFMTATPPGTADAFPQSNAPIQDEERDIPERSWNSGNEWITDFAGKTVWFVPSIKAGNDIANCLRKNGKKVIQLSRKTFDTEYQKTKLNDWDFVV
>tr|M4KW32|M4KW32_BACIU Choline ABC transporter (ATP-binding protein) OS=Bacillus subtilis XF-1 GN=opuBA PE=4 SV=1 Split=0 
MLTLENVSKTYKGGKKAVNNVNLKIAKGEFICFIGPSGCGKTTTMKMINRLIEPSAGKIFIDGENIMDQDPVELRRKIGYVIQQIGLFPHMTIQQNISLVPKLLKWPEQQRKERARELLKLVDMGPEYVDRYPHELSGGQQQRIGVLRALAAEPPLILMDEPFGALDPITRDSLQEEFKKLQKTLHKTIVFVTHDMDEAIKLADRIVILKAGEIVQVGTPDDILRNPADEFVEEFIGKERLIQSSSPDVERVDQIMNTQPVTITADKTLSEAIQLMRQERVDSLLVVDDEHVLQGYVDVEIIDQCRKKANLIGEVLHEDIYTVLGGTLLRDTVRKILKRGVKYVPVVDEDRRLIGIVTRASLVDIVYDSLWGEEKQLAALS
>sp|Q8AWH3|SX17A_XENTR Transcription factor Sox-17-alpha OS=Xenopus tropicalis GN=sox17a PE=2 SV=1 Split=0 
MSSPDGGYASDDQNQGKCSVPIMMTGLGQCQWAEPMNSLGEGKLKSDAGSANSRGKAEARIRRPMNAFMVWAKDERKRLAQQNPDLHNAELSKMLGKSWKALTLAEKRPFVEEAERLRVQHMQDHPNYKYRPRRRKQVKRMKRADTGFMHMAEPPESAVLGTDGRMCLESFSLGYHEQTYPHSQLPQGSHYREPQAMAPHYDGYSLPTPESSPLDLAEADPVFFTSPPQDECQMMPYSYNASYTHQQNSGASMLVRQMPQAEQMGQGSPVQGMMGCQSSPQMYYGQMYLPGSARHHQLPQAGQNSPPPEAQQMGRADHIQQVDMLAEVDRTEFEQYLSYVAKSDLGMHYHGQESVVPTADNGPISSVLSDASTAVYYCNYPSA
```

Comment: How did you create this input string? Its syntax is problematic because it uses commas to separate both segments and elements within a segment. That makes it harder to parse.

Comment: The commas just indicate next element. I wasnt sure how to format that in my question. I will try to put it in a table.

Comment: If possible, add the data (or a small subset thereof) in a way that can be copy-pasted for easier reproducibility

Comment: from the dataset or from the "keyLabelRun" list (python array)?

Comment: Both. It's not clear how you create the `keyLabelRun`

Comment: Also, what's your expected output?

Comment: keyLabelRun is just a 16k+ element list. The dataset is protein bioinformatic sequences.

Comment: I was thinking I should just append everything I'm looking for in another list.

Comment: Do you expect a single string for each OS entry? e.g. first result would be "Dengue virus 3"? Also, is the input you posted a text file?

Comment: That would be perfect! :D

Comment: No the input is a python list, where each element has a string in it.

Comment: Are the line numbers part of these strings? I was asking for the original data source because this string list isn't optimal to work with.

Comment: no, i just wanted to show the index. I will post a couple lines of the dataset.

Comment: Please post the raw original data without additions. Otherwise it's difficult to come up with a solution. If it's a Python list, then post that. If it's a text file, then post that.

Comment: I added a sample of the dataset to the bottom of the post

Answer (score 0):

I got it! :D

```
OSarr = []
G = 0
for i in range(len(keyLabelrun)):
    OSarr.append(keyLabelrun[G])
    G += 1
    if keyLabelrun[G].count('='):
        while keyLabelrun[G].count('OS=') != 1:
            G+=1
```

Maybe next time everyone, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Due to the syntax, you have to keep track of which part (OS, PE, etc) you're currently parsing. Here's a function to extract the species name from the FASTA header:

```py
def extract_species(description):
    species_parts = []
    is_os = False
    for word in description.split():
        if word[:3] == 'OS=':
            is_os = True
            species_parts.append(word[3:])
        elif '=' in word:
            is_os = False
        elif is_os:
            species_parts.append(word)

    return ' '.join(species_parts)
```

You can call it when processing your input file, e.g.:

```py
from Bio import SeqIO

for record in SeqIO.parse('input.fa', 'fasta'):
    species = extract_species(record.description)
```

Comment: lol, why didnt you just say "there might be a Bio python function to do it."? xDD

Comment: I forgot all about bioPython 

Comment: are you calling it while also using a bioPython function?

Comment: my version of bioPython is not liking "rec.description.split()"

Comment: @NormanSabin sorry, I had a wrong variable name from a previous version. Fixed now.

Comment: This doesn't use BioPython (except for the loading of the fasta file), it's just simple text processing. I don't think there's anything in BioPython for this use case since the FASTA format is very simple.

Comment: @NormanSabin did this solve your problem or do you need any more help?

Comment: Sorry I moved on once I solved it. Ill check this tonight (its 1pm right now) and accept it if it works, but thank you for reminding me about biopython either way